# How to fix plpgsql LIKE condition non-integer type not found?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created function in PostgreSQL for looping, when this function running there is checking running first. Is this function still running with same parameter? If no then go else end. But I found issue for LIKE condition if the parameter is non-integer value.

I've tested for integer value :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.looping(sys_date timestamp, n integer, meber_code varchar)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
  checkFunctionRunning integer := 0;
  queryRunning text;
  concatText text := '%LOOPING%'||$2||'%';
BEGIN
 RAISE NOTICE 'Concat: %', concatText;
 SELECT COUNT(1) INTO checkFunctionRunning 
 FROM pg_stat_activity 
 WHERE 1=1
 AND UPPER(state)='ACTIVE' 
 --AND UPPER(query) LIKE '%LOOPING(timestamp '||$1||',%'
 AND UPPER(query) LIKE concatText
 AND UPPER(query) NOT LIKE '%PG_STAT%'
 ;
 IF checkFunctionRunning = 1 THEN
 FOR counter IN 1..n LOOP
 RAISE NOTICE 'Counter: %, Nilai N : %, Param 3 : %', counter,n,$3;
 PERFORM pg_sleep(10);
   END LOOP;
 return n;
 ELSE
    --return '%select looping('||$1||');% '||$1||'-'||checkFunctionRunning;
    SELECT query||' - this is queryRunning '||checkFunctionRunning into queryRunning
    FROM pg_stat_activity 
    WHERE 1=1
    AND UPPER(state)='ACTIVE' 
    AND UPPER(query) LIKE concatText
    AND UPPER(query) NOT LIKE '%PG_STAT%'
    ;
    return queryRunning;
    --return 'Currently there is function running with same parameters';
 END IF;
END ; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.looping(timestamp,integer,varchar)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

then I run using this code below :

```
select looping(now()::timestamp,10,'Param3');
```

The function working properly.
Result :

```
NOTICE:  Concat: %LOOPING%10%
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 7 at RAISE
NOTICE:  Counter: 1, Nilai N : 10, Param 3 : Param3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 18 at RAISE
NOTICE:  Counter: 2, Nilai N : 10, Param 3 : Param3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 18 at RAISE
NOTICE:  Counter: 3, Nilai N : 10, Param 3 : Param3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 18 at RAISE
NOTICE:  Counter: 4, Nilai N : 10, Param 3 : Param3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 18 at RAISE
NOTICE:  Counter: 5, Nilai N : 10, Param 3 : Param3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 18 at RAISE
NOTICE:  Counter: 6, Nilai N : 10, Param 3 : Param3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 18 at RAISE
NOTICE:  Counter: 7, Nilai N : 10, Param 3 : Param3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 18 at RAISE
NOTICE:  Counter: 8, Nilai N : 10, Param 3 : Param3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 18 at RAISE
NOTICE:  Counter: 9, Nilai N : 10, Param 3 : Param3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 18 at RAISE
NOTICE:  Counter: 10, Nilai N : 10, Param 3 : Param3
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 18 at RAISE
Total query runtime: 10.0 secs
1 row retrieved.
```

Then I changed

```
concatText text := '%LOOPING%'||$2||'%';
```

into

```
concatText text := '%LOOPING%'||$2||','||quote_literal($3)||'%';
```

then I got result :

```
NOTICE:  Concat: %LOOPING%10,'Param3'%
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function looping(timestamp without time zone,integer,character varying) line 7 at RAISE

Total query runtime: 13 msec
1 row retrieved.
"Currently there is function running with same parameters - 0"
```

Is my concatText for LIKE condition wrong?

Regards,
Students

Comment: Cast `$2` to text. `concatText text := '%LOOPING%'||$2::text||'%';`

Comment: $2 is integer, if integer the function result is expected result. the problem is when i'm using $1 and $3 in LIKE condition. because I want all parameters should be included in LIKE conditions.

Comment: The other thing I would try is this: `concatText text := ('%LOOPING%'||$2||','||quote_literal($3)||'%');`. Concatenated text is tough for postgres to parse sometimes. So if you add parenthesis it forces it to parse the way you want it and not something like `('%LOOPING%'||$2||','||quote_literal($3))||'%'` by accident.